# Umbraco, POST when inheriting from RenderMVCController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have set up a document type in Umbraco, and have created a custom controller & model for this document type.

The custom controller inherits from : `RenderMvcController` class and the views inherit the model through `@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<com.something.model>`

This all works fine for any `HttpGet` requests. However as soon as I want to do a form post back to the controller using `@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("SomeAction", "SomeController", null,  new { @class = "some-class" }))`

I get the following error message: `Could not find a Surface controller route in the RouteTable for controller name SomeController`

From all the documentation that I was able to find it always refers to SurfaceControllers when it comes to form posts. Is there a way to change the routing so that it would post to my custom controller, rather then another controller that inherits from the `SurfaceController` class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inherit your `Controller` from `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController`

You can do this in controller like this:

```
public class DefaultController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController
{
   Public ActionResult YourMethod()
   {
       return CurrentUmbracoPage();
   }
}
```

In View you call the Form like:

```
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("YourMethod", "Default",new { @class = "YourclassName" }))
{
    //DO Something
}
```

Now final step is to define your Route in RouteConfig.cs in App_Start Folder

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Default", action = "YourMethod", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this for your form:

```
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm("Post", "ControllerNameWithoutController", System.Web.Mvc.FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "YourclassName" }))
```

Also your controller must be inherited from SurfaceController

```
 public class YourControllerNameController : SurfaceController
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a good solution to allow get and post verbs to the same controller. As you cant inherit from both the RenderMvcController and SurfaceController then I have found this better, it also allows the use of the RenderModel for populating form elements.

```
 public class ContactUsController : SurfaceController, IRenderController
```

Comment: Also to pass the view model back in(like in normal mvc), you will need something like this in your model
        public ContactUsViewModel() : this(new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current).TypedContent(UmbracoContext.Current.PageId)) { }
        public ContactUsViewModel(IPublishedContent content) : base(content) { }